# Aplicar a una variable de la clase A el valor de un atributo de la clase B

Tags: java, poo

Estoy con un problema en el desarrollo de un programa en java, necesito setear en una varibale de una clase Menú el valor seteado a un atributo de la clase Logica.

clase Logica

```
public class Logica {

    public static boolean administrador = false;
    public int usIngresado = LogIn.cedula;
    public String pwdIngresado = LogIn.ci;

    public void checkUser (int usIngresado, String pwdIngresado) {//determinación de Admin
        int usuario = usIngresado , usAdmin = 123456, usRec = 456789;
        String pass = pwdIngresado, pwdAd = "admin", pwdRec = "user";
        if (usuario == usAdmin && pass.equals(pwdAd)) {
            System.out.println("Ingresa en administrador");
            administrador = true;
        }
    }
}
```

El método funciona, lo he probado con impresiones, y el setea el valor a administrador según el usuario. El tema es que no he logrado desde la clase Menú, obtener ese valor (**true** o **false**) para validar botones y ventanas. Logrando que Menú lo lea correctamente es acomodarlo para el resto de las ventanas que estoy trabajando.

Consulta resultante: como hago para obtener el valor de administrador y guardarlo en la variable validacion de la clase Menú?
O como hago para leer directamente el valor, sin nececsidad de duplicar el dato en otra variable?

Como aclaración, con mi docente no puedo contar, ya que no explica dice "investiguen".... y en eso estoy ahora.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Clases de paquetes separados dentro del mismo proyecto.

Comment: pon el código de tu otra clase donde estás intentando llamarla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tú código debes cambiar el `void` de `checkUser` por `boolean` y devolver la variable `administrador` con `return`:

```
public class Logica {

    public static boolean administrador = false;
    public int usIngresado = LogIn.cedula;
    public String pwdIngresado = LogIn.ci;

    public boolean checkUser (int usIngresado, String pwdIngresado) {//determinación de Admin
        int usuario = usIngresado , usAdmin = 123456, usRec = 456789;
        String pass = pwdIngresado, pwdAd = "admin", pwdRec = "user";
        if (usuario == usAdmin && pass.equals(pwdAd)) {
            System.out.println("Ingresa en administrador");
            administrador = true;
        }
        return administrador;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambié por tu código, dejando `checUser` como `boolean` y retornando `administrador`. Muchas gracias!!

```
public class Logica {    
    public static boolean administrador = false;

    public boolean checkUser (int usIngresado, String pwdIngresado) {//determinación de Admin
        int usuario = usIngresado , usAdmin = 39830638, usRec = 16866983;
        String pass = pwdIngresado, pwdAd = "admin", pwdRec = "user";
        if (usuario == usAdmin && pass.equals(pwdAd)) {
            System.out.println("Ingresa en administrador");
            administrador = true;
        }
        System.out.println("estado administrador:   " + administrador);
        return administrador;
    }

    public boolean getAdministrador () {
        return administrador;
    }

    public void setAdministrador(boolean administrador) {
        this.administrador = administrador;
    }
}
```

Lo que tenía en `MenuPpal`era:

```
  public class MenuPpal extends JFrame {


        //saqué todo lo que 
        //corresponde a la importación
        //de clases gráficas

        if (admin.getAdministrador()) {
                btnGestUsrs.setEnabled(true);//habilito el botón
            }
        else {
                btnGestUsrs.setEnabled(false);//no habilito el botón
            }
}
```

LA SOLUCIÓN:
Aunque haya gente a la que le pueda parecer intuitivo o muy fácil, luego de desenredar ideas, lo único que debía hacer era invocar directamente ese atributo, lisa y llanamente. Aquí va mi modificación al `if` de arriba.

```
  public class MenuPpal extends JFrame {

        Logica admin = new Logica();

        //saqué todo lo que 
        //corresponde a la importación
        //de clases gráficas

        if (Logica.administrador) {//si quiero saber si es true el boolean de la condición no es necesario hacerla explicita, por eso no pongo el (== true), ahora si lo que me interesa es saber si es false, si debo poner la condición completa

                btnGestUsrs.setEnabled(true);//habilito el botón
            }
        else {
                btnGestUsrs.setEnabled(false);//no habilito el botón
            }
}
```

Y lo mas importante de mi problema era el momento en que instanciaba el método que guardaba el valor en `administrador`, quedaba debajo de la apertura de la ventana donde solicitaba el valor de `administrador`.

el código que me afectaba es éste,  que estaba en una tercer clase (un jframe) en el que nunca me fijé.

```
                log.setUsIngresado(Integer.parseInt(ci));
                log.setPwdIngresado(pass);

                boolean validar = ValCed.esCIValida(ci);


                if (validar == true && log.Loggeo(log.getUsIngresado(), log.getPwdIngresado())) {
                    MenuPpal abrir = new MenuPpal();
                    abrir.setVisible(true);
                    LogIn.this.dispose();
                }
                else {
                    lblCedValida.setText("Datos No Válidos");
                }
                usr.setUsIngresado(Integer.parseInt(ci));
                usr.setPwdIngresado(pass);
                usr.checkUser(usr.getUsIngresado(), usr.getPwdIngresado());//así nunca paso los parámetros ni logro ejecutar el método para darle el valor a administrador
            }
        });
        btnIngresar.setBounds(201, 144, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnIngresar);
```

Ésta es la corrección:

```
                log.setUsIngresado(Integer.parseInt(ci));
                log.setPwdIngresado(pass);

                boolean validar = ValCed.esCIValida(ci);

                usr.setUsIngresado(Integer.parseInt(ci));
                usr.setPwdIngresado(pass);
                usr.checkUser(usr.getUsIngresado(), usr.getPwdIngresado());//aquí es donde paso los parámetros para darle valor a administrador


                if (validar == true && log.Loggeo(log.getUsIngresado(), log.getPwdIngresado())) {
                    MenuPpal abrir = new MenuPpal();
                    abrir.setVisible(true);
                    LogIn.this.dispose();
                }
                else {
                    lblCedValida.setText("Datos No Válidos");
                }
            }
        });
        btnIngresar.setBounds(201, 144, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnIngresar);
```

Concepto básico de la Programación: conjunto de ÓRDENES ORDENADAS!!! nunca olviden eso, en que orden están sus órdenes! Gracias a quienes me ayudaron!